# I stopped Terminal with "killall -STOP Terminal" how to -CONT it back?

Tags: terminal, macos

I used terminal for long 3D render overnight. I planned for the rendering to be finished in the morning, but it was finished only half way.

To prevent losing the progress and to continue using the computer without lag I decided to pause the terminal.

I opened a new Terminal window and entered: "killall -STOP Terminal".
Everything was fine, Terminal was paused, but now I don't understand how to continue Terminal.

I can't open new Terminal window and "Force Quit" window doesn't allow me to continue the app.

**How to continue Terminal?**

Should I make a copy of Terminal app maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Script Editor from the Utilities folder and run the following:

```
do shell script "killall -CONT Terminal"
```